# Create index in elastic search using java to create MongoDB river

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

Create MongoDB river in Elasticsearch using Java API

```
client.index(Requests.indexRequest("_river").type("my_river").id("_meta").source(source)).actionGet();
```

How to create source for an above mentioned code.
i need to create mongodb river in elasticsearch , i am able to search using curl commands,
But need help to create index and searching form java application